# Angular2 RC: Added controls with addControls method after creation of the ControlGroup is not working

Tags: angular, formbuilder, angular2-forms

I have a from that adds different fields (I am adding new controls because just hiding them from the template using *ngIf does not exclude them from the form and therefore results in invalid form) based on the selected option from a select option. I am adding new controls to the available form using addControl method of a form in Angular2. The controls are being added correctly, but I don't know why the values of those added controls are not being updated after user inputs. Here is the way I am adding new controls to the form:

```
signUpForm: ControlGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.signUpForm = this.fb.group({
        firstName: ["", Validators.required],
        lastName: ["", Validators.required],
        group: ["", Validators.required]
    });
}

modifyControls(selectedGroup): number {
    if (selectedGroup == 1) {
        if (this.signUpForm.contains("studentID")) {
            this.signUpForm.removeControl("studentID");
        }
        this.signUpForm.addControl("teacherCode", new Control("", Validators.required));//need some custome validations
        this.signUpForm.addControl("teacherID", new Control("", Validators.required));
        return 1;
    }
    else if (selectedGroup == 2) {
        if (this.signUpForm.contains("teacherCode")) {
            this.signUpForm.removeControl("teacherCode");
            this.signUpForm.removeControl("teacherID");
        }
        this.signUpForm.addControl("studentID", new Control("", Validators.required));
        return 2;
    }
}
```

It looks like that angular does not recognized those new fields. I think it is something related to AbstractControl but the documentation lacks on that. Here is the snapshot of the problem, that the dynamically added controls are not being picked up by angular.
[image]

To show the problem I have created a simple example in the following plunker (please go to version 2 to replicate this problem).

https://plnkr.co/edit/RI4JL4Pnf2LrJ3TsxsSt?p=preview

What am i doing wrong and how make it work with the current setup?
What are other options for achieving the same behavior?

Thank you for your help

**Workaround:**

```
modifyControls(selectedGroup) {
    if (selectedGroup == 1) {
        this.signUpForm.controls['teacherCode'].validator = Validators.required;
        this.signUpForm.controls['teacherCode'].updateValueAndValidity();
        this.signUpForm.controls['teacherID'].validator = Validators.required;
        this.signUpForm.controls['teacherID'].updateValueAndValidity(); 
        this.signUpForm.controls['studentID'].validator = null;
        this.signUpForm.controls['studentID'].updateValueAndValidity();
    }
    else if (selectedGroup == 2) {
        this.signUpForm.controls['teacherCode'].validator = null;
        this.signUpForm.controls['teacherCode'].updateValueAndValidity();
        this.signUpForm.controls['teacherID'].validator = null;
        this.signUpForm.controls['teacherID'].updateValueAndValidity();
        this.signUpForm.controls['studentID'].validator = Validators.required;
        this.signUpForm.controls['studentID'].updateValueAndValidity(); 

    }
}
```

Comment: I found a workaround to my case by adding validators and updating them on the flight, but because I still have not found the reason that my original code was not working I am not closing the question as solved.

Answer (score 1):

For example to do the `required` validation only when `teacherCode.value` has a value:

```
    this.signUpForm.addControl("teacherCode", new Control("", 
        (c:Control) => { 
          if(this.signUpForm.controls['teacherID'].value) {
            return Validators.required(c);
          }
        })
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I get an error that cannot access controls property of undefined. I updated my question to have a snapshot of the problem.

Comment: That doesn't work either. I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined. It seems it is not being created by the time it reaches the validators.

Comment: Maybe `teacherID` doesn't exist at that time. I didn't bother to investigate what you actually want to validate. Besifes that I'm sure it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but even in your example as soon as I change the (this.signUpForm.controls.firstName.value) to (this.signUpForm.controls.teacherCode.value)  which has been added dynamically it gives me the same error. I looks like even though the name are the same the objects are different and angular cannot find them,

Comment: Hey Gunter,
I tried to make your method work in my case (my last plunker version). It works for the first change of the select options, but if the user changes his selection from teacher to student the validators are still attached and form validation won't be successful. Besides not sure why addControls does not work the way I want to use.??